# How to force a resolution on Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, resolution, display-adapter

I have a machine with Windows 7 x64 and 2 screens.

Both Samsung,

> a **SyncMaster 2443NW (max 1920x1200)** and a **SyncMaster 2032MW (max 1680x1050)**

Problem is that the **2032MW** on Windows 7 one only gives this ranges:

[image]

And the 24'' monitor, only gives a maximum of **1600x1200** !

I tried installing the Samsung drivers but they do nothing, the Graphic card is capable of such resolutions as it's an **NVidia GeForce 9800 GT** with 1024Mb Ram

on my MacBook Pro I have no problems in showing this as there is a nice application called SwitchResX that I can set any resolution.

What can I do in my Windows 7 machine?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Check the NVIDIA Control Panel, you should be able to add a custom resolution and enable it from there.

Comment: will try that, thxs

Comment: No luck :( it allows to add, but soon I press the Test, it says "Failed", add to add 1679x1050 in order to work... weird!  :(

Comment: http://forums.macrumors.com/showthread.php?t=848676

Answer (score 7):

In Device Manager, try manually installing a driver for your monitor. Right-click Computer, then click Manage. Expand Monitors, then right-click your monitor and click "Update driver software...". Click "Browse my computer", then "Pick from a list". Uncheck "Show compatible hardware" and select the "Digital Flat Panel" for your monitor.

Comment: You. I love you.

Comment: What if the wanted resolution not showing in the list? like typical 2560x1440

Answer (score 0):

Guys Its actually really simple
Right-click on your computer and scroll over to properties,
Properties of computer

[image]

Check if your computer is second, third, or Fourth Generation,
Go to google chrome and search "intel hd graphics for 2nd gen Windows 7" if your computer is the second generation. download the latest Intel graphics that support Windows 7 and install them.
Restart your computer and try and go to your display settings, I assure you it works

Answer (score -1):

If you lost 1400×900 when installing Windows 10, try downloading NVIDIA driver 307.74 WHQL, using `clean install` setting.

Comment: The 307.74 WHQL release does not support Windows 10.  Using 307.74 would likely make the problem worst and result in the system not being bootable.