# Detect Displays on Windows?

Tags: windows, windows-vista, resolution, display, kvm-switch

Is there anyway to do something like Mac OS X's "Detect Displays" on Windows (Vista Business, SP2)?

I have two monitors connected to two computers, one of them through a KVM-switch. When Windows is started or unlocked while not the active computer on the switch, the screen resolution is set to 1024 x 768 on the switched screen. It is also reported as the largest size the screen can handle, so I can't just reset it to its native 1680 x 1050.

On my Mac, I can just use System Preferences -> Displays -> Detect Displays to make the OS pick up that it's actually a bigger screen, but I haven't been able to find something like this on Windows. Tips or suggestions?

**Edit**: If I reboot the PC while it is the active computer in the KVM switch, I can change the resolution to 1680 x 1050 without a problem. The issue is that the KVM switch is reporting a max resolution of 1024 x 768 and I can't get Windows to detect that there's another screen at the end of the cable without a reboot.

Comment: What model/make KVM?

Comment: @Tog: It's one of these: http://www.aten.com/products/productItem.php?pid=20090605160622001&psid=20070130114323002&pcid=20070130111333003&layerid=subClass3

Comment: What graphics card are you using?  Also, is the other computer on the KVM using the proper resolution?

Comment: @MBraedley: The graphics card is an ATI Radeon HD 2600 XT. My Mac also changes the resolution to 1024 x 768 if I start it while it's not the active computer in the KVM, but I can just do a "Detect Displays" to have it pick up the right display again.

Comment: There is a great big honking 'Detect' button in the Display Properties in Windows 7.  I thought Vista has this functionality but if the button isn't there I don't know what to tell you, as I don't have a Vista image handy I can poke around with. :/

Comment: @Shinrai - Vista does indeed have the Detect button

Comment: Thanks, I'll see if I can find that button tomorrow when I'm back at work. In the meantime, why don't @Shinrai or @Joe Taylor write their comment as an answer so I can give you rep?

Comment: I did find the button on my Windows 7 virtual machine, but I haven't been able to find it on my Vista. Can anyone with access to Vista find this button and post a screenshot of it?

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://superuser.com/questions/157256

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(Moving comment to answer per @Lizzan's request, although I didn't quite think it warranted being an answer)

There is a great big honking 'Detect' button in the Display Properties in Windows 7.  I know Vista has this functionality (at least, I recall being able to do it in XP as well so why would it be missing?)but if the button isn't there I don't know what to tell you, as I don't have a Vista image handy I can poke around with. :/

Comment: Since my question was "Is there anyway to do something like Mac OS X's "Detect Displays" on Windows (Vista)?", and you say there's such a button, I'd say it counts as an answer! =)

Comment: It may NOT have the button though.  See, I'm not sure.  I can't think of any valid reason it WOULDN'T though...

Comment: @Shinrai: Could you possibly add a screenshot of where I can find this button - I have a Swedish OS and I'm not sure that I'm in the right place because I can't  find the button you've mentioned.

Comment: I did find the button on my Windows 7 virtual machine, but I haven't been able to find it on my Vista. Can anyone with access to Vista find this button and post a screenshot of it?

Comment: @Lizzan - Looks like my fears were correct.  Hope somebody's able to find this for you.

Comment: @Shinrai: Awarded you the bounty as you at least let me know there's supposed to be a solution, and showing it exists on Win7. Thanks for helping out!

Comment: @Lizzan - Sorry I couldn't do any better.  I'm frankly surprised that nobody knows how to do this in Vista!

Comment: @Shinrai: No problems! I'm glad there's a solution for Win7 at least, I should probably ask for an OS update anyways...:-)

Answer (score 1):

On Windows 7 you can press `[WindowsKey]-P` and choose between single, clone and extend.

This also detects the monitor if it's currently not seen – useful when the second monitor is lost after a KVM switching etc.

Answer (score 0):

If you can't change the resolution to be any higher, then it is probably a limitation of the graphics card. You can look your graphics card model number up online to see if it supports a resolution of 1680 x 1050.

Comment: The graphics card supports the resolution fine, if I restart the computer while it is the active computer in the KVM-switch. I'll edit my question to add that.

Answer (score 0):

First right click you desktop, then click screen resolution. At the top right there is two buttons Detect and Identify this is probably what you are looking for.

Comment: Is this on Vista? Could you please provide a screenshot, because I can't find the Detect button, only the Identify one.

Comment: What version of vista? You will have to wait until I get home tonight for a screen shot.

Comment: Vista Business, SP2